# Is it possible to include a file that Git doesn't think has changed?

Tags: git

I've updated my favicon and so have had to replace the existing `favicon.ico` file with a new `favicon.ico` file. Clearly since the names are the same Git doesn't think that anything has changed. Is there a way to force it to be included as part of a commit?

Comment: Git should know the files changed, even if the name is the same. Are you sure it is indeed a different file? `git status` does not show the file as modified?

Comment: Have you compared the hashes of the two favicon.ico files (git does the same)?

Comment: That's ***that*** key feature of version control systems like git: Noticing the differences of a file even though the file's name stays the same. You must have done sth else wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

git doesn't rely on just a change of filename to detect that a file has been modified. [It uses information returned by `lstat`.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/racy-git.txt)

If, somehow, you have changed the contents of the file without changing what `lstat` returns for it, then git will think it's unchanged. The fix is simply to `touch` the file (e.g. `touch favicon.ico`) to change its `lstat` data.

If git still thinks the file is unchanged after you `touch` it, then either you didn't actually change the file contents, or the file is ignored (e.g. by `.gitignore`), or you told git in some other way to ignore changes to the file (e.g. `git update-index --assume-unchanged`).

Answer (score 0):

Git should definetly notice changes of such files even if the name won't change. Git even notices if you just change rights of files under linux. That's why you should be careful with `chmod` and `chown` when using recursively. However this could happen when using the `--assume-unchanged` option. However, this could be stopped for a certain file.

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/to/file
```

Comment: Objection! ;-) The only attribute git is aware of is the x (executable) flag. Git doesn't care about the others (such as rw) and neither does it record ownership.